# XCode and Simulator suddenly crashed and froze my Macbook

Tags: freeze, macbook, xcode, simulator

I am using a MacBook Pro 13-inch 2020 (i5, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD) and using Xcode and Simulator to build my first app. However, when I run the Simulator, my MacBook freezes, and I can't do anything other than performing a hard restart (my project is very simple because I'm just learning Swift and SwiftUI). Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and how did you resolve it?

I've been using Xcode from version 13 up to the current version (14.3.1), and this issue continues to happen. Could it be that my MacBook is too old to build Swift projects?

[MY PROJECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtI09.jpg)

[ACTIVITY MONITOR - CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdqfK.jpg)

[ACTIVITY MONITOR - MEMORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMLJg.jpg)

Comment: Get screenshots of Activity Monitor, CPU & Memory windows, right as you launch [assuming you can get in before the freeze]. That might give us some clues.

Comment: I added some screenshots of Activity Monitor when running my project 